# Specify format to NotebookSave

Tags: front-end, export, notebooks

When I save a Mathematica notebook using the front-end Save dialog, I can specify the format:

[image: Screenshot of Save dialog window]

However, the documentation for the `NotebookSave` command indicates only that

> `NotebookSave[notebook, "file"]` saves the notebook in the specified file

Is there a way to specify the format when using `NotebookSave`, like I can when using the visual save dialog? I use Mathematica 9.

Comment: I'm assuming that `NotebookSave[EvaluationNotebook[], "file.nb", Interactive -> True]` is not what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NotebookSave` saves a Mathematica notebook as is, without converting it to other formats.

To convert to other formats, such as PDF, use `Export`.  Example:

```
nb = Notebooks[][[1]]
Export["~/Desktop/nb.pdf", nb]
```